# Download file in background when app is inactive without newsstand in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

I have the following problem. Each week on a friday a list with content is published. The iOS App should check on a specific time on that friday for this list and process the data in background. Also if the app is in background. I can't use normal Push-Notifications, because the user should get a Local Notification if the content in the list matches some local settings. Newsstand is not an option, because the app has nothing to do with a magazine and i have no subscriptions. Are there any options to do this without server-side infrastructure? 
Thanks in advance.
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understan from your question you want to run your app once a week even if the app is on background. I made a lot of researsh on this topic(keeping an app alive in background) but expect for applications using Vo-IP, playing Audio, and locations services are rejected by Apple. But if you want to just download the data in background(not to tire UI) u can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a third party like [ASIHTTPReques](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to handle them in background easily. I repeat once again, this kind stays alive(as far as i know) about ten minutes, but you can not fire a scheduled timer(of NSTimer) or something else on background.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I think I will have to rework the concept with the client.

Comment: In fact you can use APNS to notify your app once a week, and when the notification is received(mean, when the app became active) create a connection with your server to download data(lets say via a GET request) and fire local notifications how you want